# Is there any way to click on 6th item of this list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

[image]

As on the image I have to click on the 6th item on the list.
I can easily do this with  `IList<IWebElement>` 
But is there any way to do the same thing with the help of `2005256` digit which is available end of the `div` tag?

Comment: Xpath with Element's attribute might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177646/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-attribute-onclick-using-xpath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a CSS Selector looking for a substring at the onclick attribute:

```
div[onclick*='2005256']
```

This will look for the client regardless of the position.
If you want by position:

```
#searchpanel-clientlist li:nth-of-type(6)
```

Comment: Wow.This is working soo smooth.

Comment: :)  Grateful in helping

Answer (score 4):

I think the CSS Selector is the best solution, but you could also loop through all the `row` elements and get the onclick attribute text with [`element.GetAttribute("onclick")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm). This should the full onclick string and now you can use your programming language to find if it contains the number and use elements that match.

Comment: Thanks Niels,But still im confused on how to use this on my code.Will it be possible to show me the exact way?

Answer (score -2):

Try the below Xpath and share your feedback

```
(//div[@class='row client - selection row'])[5]
```